# How to get the value of the first column of current row of Winform DataGridView?

Tags: datagridview

This is something simple yet I cannot find any answer searching google !

I tried this in C#

```
MessageBox.Show(this.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].ToString());
```

This returns me row and column index not the value of the cell.

How to get the value instead ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference the value:

```
MessageBox.Show(this.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```